# How to get the actual buffer size in samples from a WASAPI device with NAudio?

Tags: c#, audio, naudio, wasapi

Is there any smart way to obtain the buffer size in samples in a precise way?

For the capture device and the render device. I've tried `mmDevice.AudioClient.BufferSize` after calling `StartRecording()` but it doesn't seem to contain a proper value but threw an exception.

Comment: what exception did it throw?

Comment: It was a COM exception, most probably due to threading issues. It seems this property can only be evaluated from the audio thread that initialized the audio client.